# Metadata rejected asking for app login details

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed an iOS app, which will control a hardware device. Apple was accepted my first version of app. When I upload my second version with in a week then they have rejected it and asking for login details. My problem is if I share the login details also they should have hardware to check the functionality. So please suggest me what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can give them the required Login Credentials and also you can make a video of your app controlling hardware and upload it to some Website like youtube,dailymotion etc and share the link with them so that They can match your app login and other screens with the actual video

Hope it will helps you.